# MediaPlayer android issue

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a listview of songs which has a separate play button with them.
I play well but I want to change the play icon to playing and if I play another then the icon of first should be reset to pause.

**This is Playing code:**

```
if(mediaPlayer!=null)
          {
              mediaPlayer.release();
              viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);

          }
          else
          {
              viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
          }
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, music.getSong());


            mediaPlayer.start();
```

as you see "ic_play" and "ic_pause" are jpg files I want to apply but I always show "ic_pause"

Please tell me what should I do to change the icons while playing and when the second one play the first one should automatically reset.

Answer (score 1):

if i got it right you should change the icons in an if/else statement like this:

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
     //TODO Set icon pause 
}else{
     //TODO Set icon play 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes in your `adapter` just replace the icon based on its playing state.

```
   if(mediaPlayer!=null)
      {  
          if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
             mediaPlayer.release();
               viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            } else{
               viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
            }

      }
```